# How to install custom shell theme using gnome-tweak-tool

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I found similar posts, but those answers didn't solve my issue. I need to know can I install custom Shell-themes in ubuntu-gnome? If yes what are the best custo shell-themes and where can I get it? In gnome-tweak-tool i cannot select anything under shell theme. Any solution? I have already installed icon themes.

Comment: Maybe this page can help: http://rlog.rgtti.com/2012/01/29/how-to-modify-a-gnome-shell-theme/ . Basically you unpack your theme under `$HOME/.themes`.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme

Comment: Install the extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/

Comment: i made it `ON`. But no installation prompt came.

Comment: after doing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` i can select shell theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome-tweak-tool was showing a triangle at shell-theme and i was not able to make a selection there. After installing ubuntu-gnome-desktop by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` i can select shell theme and now i am able to do this: http://rlog.rgtti.com/2012/01/29/how-to-modify-a-gnome-shell-theme/. Still looking for a better gnome-shell-theme.

Answer (score 2):

The Numix theme is my personal favourite. To install it -

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme`

Otherwise, download the theme file and extract the theme file to `/usr/share/themes`.

To set the theme -

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix"`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Numix"`

where Numix can be replaced with the name of the theme.

Comment: after these command i am getting my terminal black, tweak tool crash.

Comment: i chose Adwaita again. gnome-tweK-tool now crashes when i click on theme shoosing menus

Comment: Replace "Numix" with "Adwaita" to get back the original theme.

Comment: Did you install Numix? At what step did the problem occur?

Comment: I dont know what made tweak tool crash. But these commands made my windows awry. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix"`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Numix"`